# Segmentation fault while using char **

Tags: c, gcc

I got a code snippet of compare section  from so. I am on a research on how to implement that compare function in my program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

 int compare(const void* a,const void* b)
 {
  char** sa=(char**)a;
  char** sb=(char**)b;
  return strcmp(*sa,*sb);
 }

int main(){

int l=compare("helloworld","hello");
printf("%d",l);

return 0;

}
```

But i am getting segmentation fault.I am a newbie to pointers in c.What modification should i make so that i get the a value for l from this program.

Comment: Are you doing some sort of exercise to test the boundaries of the C++ language? If not, there is absolutely no need to cast the pointers to `void*`, nor to use a second level of indirection. Not to mention, that you could have used `std::string` and the equality operator.

Comment: @patatahooligan This question is clearly about C, not C++.

Comment: @idmean sorry I thought I'd clicked the C++ tag. My mistake!

Comment: Why are you using `char **` to begin with? Your character strings can be referenced simply with `char *`. The problem is that you're trying to treat `char *` inputs to your `compare` function as `char **` values. They simply are not that. `*sa` and `*sb` point to the first few bytes of each of your strings and `strcmp(*sa, *sb)` is treating those results as if they were themselves char pointers. They are not valid addresses. Thus the seg fault.

Comment: @ pattaahooligan . I am trying to this in c.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything useful in your `compare` method other than calling the library function `strcmp`. Just replace it with the following:

```
 int compare(const char* a,const char* b)
 {
    return strcmp(a,b);
 }
```

However, if you still want to convert the char * point to void * back and forth, you can do it the following way:

```
int compare(const void* a,const void* b)
 {
  char** sa=(char**)&a;
  char** sb=(char**)&b;
  return strcmp(*sa,*sb);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dereferencing your strings "hello" as addresses, which are invalid.  sa and sb are pointers to pointers to characters, but a and b are just pointers (that happen to be pointers to characters.)  You could either use:

```
char** sa=(char**)&a;
char** sb=(char**)&b;
```

Which means set sa and sb to the address of pointers a and b (which happen to be pointers to characters and therefor pointers to pointers to characters) or:

```
int compare(const void** a,const void** b)

char** sa=(char**)a;
char** sb=(char**)b;

...

int l=compare(&"helloworld",&"hello");
```

which means pass the address of a pointer to the first byte of "hello" (a pointer to a pointer)

or the way most people would do it:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

 int compare(const void* a,const void* b)
 {
  char* sa=(char *)a;
  char* sb=(char *)b;
  return strcmp(sa,sb);
 }

int main(){

int l=compare("helloworld","hello");
printf("%d",l);

return 0;

}
```

Unless there is some reason why you need sa and sb to be pointers to pointers to characters, of course.

Comment: No need to cast `void`-pointers in C. `char * sa = a;` will perfectly do.